# I can't pull data other than input with ajax

Tags: php, json, ajax, input

I have a modal I opened with Ajax and I can pull the information from the database. My problem is this: I can only pull data into the input. Any div, p tags or ckeditor etc. I can't pull data into it. What can I do about this? In the meantime, I do not have problems withdrawing data from the database. I can pull the data. I'm looking at Console. But I can only pull it into the input.

index.php

```
      <div class="modal fade edit" id="edit-modal">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title pl-3" id="exampleModalScrollableTitle">Edit Test</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true" class="text-white">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <form method="post" id="frmedit" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="modal-body pre-scrollable">
                            <input type="text" name="id" id="id" class="form-control">
                            <p id="asd"></p>
                            <div class="form-group form-float mt-3">
                                <div class="form-line">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title">
                                    <label class="form-label">Title</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group form-float">
                                <label class="form-label">CKeditor</label>
                                <textarea name="test1"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn bg-grey waves-effect" data dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <input type="submit" id="update" class="btn bg-purple waves-effect" value="Save">
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click' , '.bn-edit' ,function(){
                    var id = this.id;
                    console.log("id:"+id+",type:test");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "read.php?id="+id+"&type=test",
                        success:function(response){
                            $("#edit-modal").modal('show');
                            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                                console.log("key:"+key+",value:"+value);
                            })
                            $("#title").val(title);
                            $("#test1").html(test1);
                            $("#asd").val(asd);
                            $("#id").val(id);
                        }
                    });
                });
            });

            function loaddata() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'read.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    data: {"type":"test_all"},
                    success:function(response){
                        $("#container").html(response);
                    }
                });
            }
            $(function () {
             CKEDITOR.replace('test1');
             CKEDITOR.config.height = 125;
            });
```

read.php:

```
 $id = $_REQUEST["id"];

    switch($_REQUEST["type"]) {

        case "test":
            if(isset($_REQUEST["id"])) {
                $result = $conn->read("test", " id='$id' ", "", "", "");
                if(!empty($result)) {
                    $responseArray["title"] = $result[0]["title"];
                    $responseArray["asd"] = $result[0]["asd"];
                    $responseArray["test1"] = $result[0]["test1"];
                    $responseArray["id"] = $result[0]["id"];

                    echo json_encode($responseArray);
                }
            }
            break;


        case "test_all":
            $result = $conn->verioku("id,title,asd", "test", "id");
            break;


        default:
            break;
    }
```

Comment: `.val()` is only for inputs. For other elements use `.text()`.

Comment: @Barmar please find a duplicate to hammer with.

Comment: Where do you set the variables `title` and `asd`?

Comment: We don't know precisely what `$conn->read` does, but it looks like your query is almost certainly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Where do you set the variables title and asd? 
$("#title").val(title);$("#asd").val(asd); => I'm posting ids here.
$responseArray["title"] = $result[0]["title"];$responseArray["asd"] = $result[0]["asd"]; => I'm pulling the data here

Comment: Dear @ADyson . I have no problems in the sql connection. But, you are right. my query can almost certainly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. Thank you for that. But I can't pull data other than input with these codes.

Comment: Dear @Barmar . val() is only for inputs. For other elements use .text() => I can try it. But it turns null.

Comment: `$("#asd").val(asd);` needs to be `$("#asd").text(asd);` because the element with id "asd" is not an input it's a `<p>`.

Comment: `Where do you set the variables title and asd? $("#title").val(title);` ...no, that **uses** the value of `title`, it doesn't **set** it. But where does `title` actually come from in the code? Nowhere that I can see. I guess it should be `response.title`, to get the value from the AJAX response? And `response.asd` and `response.id` as well. It would seem to make more sense.

Comment: Dear @ADyson . Firstly, i know; p,div or ckeditor is not a input. This is my problem. I can try text().But it is return null.
"it should be response.title, to get the value from the AJAX response? And response.asd and response.id as well. It would seem to make more sense. " => I am trying now.

Comment: Dear @Adyson . I tried to get the value from the Ajax response and ı used html(response.title) . It is  run in p tags. But I still can't pull data into the ckeditor.

Comment: which field is your CKEditor field? And please show also the code for initialising the CKEditor.

Comment: @ADyson , I forgot to add the html domain where ckeditor is located but ı have added now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem solved. I added just this code:
CKEDITOR.instances.ic_ozet.setData(response.ic_ozet);
Thank you so much for your comments.

```
$(document).on('click' , '.bn-edit' ,function(){
                    var id = this.id;
                    console.log("id:"+id+",type:test");
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "read.php?id="+id+"&type=test",
                        success:function(response){
                            $("#edit-modal").modal('show');
                            $.each(response, function(key, value) {
                                console.log("key:"+key+",value:"+value);
                            })
                            $("#title").val(title);
                            CKEDITOR.instances.test1.setData(response.test1);
                            $("#asd").html(asd);
                            $("#id").val(id);
                        }
                    });
                });
```

Comment: `$("#asd").val(asd);` still won't do anything.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment.